# Aurelia dynamic load

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is there a possibility with Aurelia to load a view with his viewmodel dynamically?
For example I have a list of modules, I click one of them and the target view will be loaded in the page. The list is not known a priori, so I can't load all modules.

model example.js

```
export class Modules{
  list = [];

  constructor(socket) {
    socket.on('update', list => this.list);
  }

  select(module) {
    //load and display the module view
  }
}
```

view example.html

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="module of list" click.delegate="$parent.select(module)">${module.name}</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="target">
    <!-- Here should be loaded the module -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does the list of modules contain?  Strings representing the module-id/url or objects (the actual module instances)?

Comment: @JeremyDanyow - it's an array of objects and the objects has one property storing the path of the module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Approach 1

Load the data in your `app.js` class's `configureRouter` method.  Once the data is loaded you can configure the router.  Just be sure to return a promise from `configureRouter`.

## Approach 2

Use Aurelia's `<compose>` element to compose the selected module with the appropriate view.

#### [Here's a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qaPrUd?p=preview)

And the code:

**app.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {MockSocket} from './mock-socket';

@inject(MockSocket)
export class App {
  list;
  selectedModule;
  
  constructor(socket) {
    socket.on('update', list => this.list = list);
  }

  select(module) {
    this.selectedModule = module;
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="module of list">
      <button type="button" click.delegate="$parent.select(module)">${module.path}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="target">
    <compose view-model.bind="selectedModule.path"></compose>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is on the right way! But how can I define which model should the view use? I tried to define it in the view with the `<require from="model.js">` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying you have some data that you want to pass to the selected view-model/view?

Comment: With the attribute `view.bind="<view.html>"` I can define the view to use, but how can I define which model should the view use?

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the code from the original version of my answer, which was posted before you changed your comment about what the list of modules contained.  I think you had initially said the list of modules were the objects and that had a view property with the url to the view.  Then you revised it to say that it was a list of objects with one property storing the module path.  Take a look at the most recent plunker (link above)- I think it's what you're looking for.  Apologies in advance if I'm misunderstanding the question

Comment: Ok, yet is perfectly what I was looking for, thank you!